# homebrew node.js devel

Tags: macos, node.js, homebrew

I have successfully installed **node.js** using **homebrew**. But homebrew did not create the include directory for all *.h files from node.js & v8.
I then tried running `brew install --devel node` without any luck.

Is there any way to install node via homebrew and have all the include files from node?
I am creating a C++ addon for node.js so need all header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should need is the `node` executable and [`node-gyp`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) for compiling.

You can read up on both of these in the [C/C++ Addons](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_addons) documentation:

> Node statically compiles all its dependencies into the executable. When compiling your module, you don't need to worry about linking to any of these libraries.

> The source code needs to be built into `hello.node`, the binary Addon. To do this we create a file called `binding.gyp` which describes the configuration to build your module in a JSON-like format. This file gets compiled by `node-gyp`.
>
> ```
> {
>   "targets": [
>     {
>       "target_name": "hello",
>       "sources": [ "hello.cc" ]
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

There are a few introductory examples covered, and each can be found as well in [rvagg's node-addon-examples](https://github.com/rvagg/node-addon-examples).

Though, you'll have to read up on [V8](http://izs.me/v8-docs/main.html) and [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv) separately ([libuv book](http://nikhilm.github.com/uvbook/)).

Comment: Thanks. I was using xcode IDE. and xcode was yelling at me as it didn't find `node.h` and `v8.h`.

Comment: @apostopher You could probably clone the repo (https://github.com/joyent/node) and point xcode at the `deps` and `src` directories. You wouldn't actually use them for compiling, but they might help xcode understand what you're doing. Only guessing, though.